# JavaScript - How to fade in an invisible button element upon completion of a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm very new to JavaScript/HTML/CSS, so I'm not sure how to go about this.

What I'm trying to do is write a script that displays some text in a specific function, then, when the function is finished displaying the text, automatically fades in an HTML button or equivalent without having to click on any specific element. I would imagine that the button would have to be inserted first and made hidden somehow, and that the fade in is a matter of changing the button's visibility. Is this possible in Javascript, or are there other (possibly easier) methods? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code so far:

```html
<!DOCTYPE=HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sandbox</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mainstyle.css">
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>   
    <p id="pid"></p>
    <script>
    
        var a = 1;
        function dialogue(){
            var message = "This message is (hopefully) a successful implementation of JS video game scrolling! <br> <br> Pretty cool, huh? Well, believe it or not, this whole page is a test for a very basic interactive story using HTML/JavaScript! <br> <br> Let's see if we can add some fade-in buttons, shall we? <br> <br> (By the way--you can click anywhere in this window to instantly clear through subsequent text scrolls.)";
            if(a <= message.length) {
                var txt = message.substring(0,a);
                document.getElementById ("pid").innerHTML = txt;
                setTimeout("dialogue()",20);
                a++;
                document.onclick = function(){
                a = message.length;
                };
            }
        };

        dialogue();


    </script>
    <button id="button1">Ooh, here's one! Click to see what it does!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show the button when the desired length has been reached (you already have the opposite condition in your code).

Maybe also improve some things:

- Avoid passing a string as first argument to `setTimeout`: it is best practice to pass a function instead.
- Avoid assigning a click handler upon each call of `dialogue`; you only need it to be defined once.
- Avoid modifying global variables from within functions where possible.
- Clipping a string with HTML can make the HTML invalid, like when you clip it halfway a `<br>`. True, browsers can cope with unclosed tags, but it would be more problematic with entities like `&nbsp;`. It is better to use plain text (including the line breaks) and assign it to the `textContent` property (or `text` jQuery function) while using the `white-space` CSS property to make sure that line breaks are rendered as such. The string can be defined with backticks (ES6) so you can just use the enter key for the line breaks.

I would also use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout` here, but that is just a personal preference:

```js
var message = `This message is (hopefully) a successful implementation of JS video game scrolling!

Pretty cool, huh? Well, believe it or not, this whole page is a test for a very basic interactive story using HTML/JavaScript!

Let's see if we can add some fade-in buttons, shall we?

(By the way--you can click anywhere in this window to instantly clear through subsequent text scrolls.)`;

var timer = setInterval(dialogue, 20);

function dialogue(add = 1){ // By default 1 character is made visible
    var len = $("#pid").text().length + add; // Get desired length
    $("#pid").text(message.substr(0, len)); // Make the change
    if (len < message.length) return; // Nothing more to do
    clearInterval(timer); // All is shown, so stop the animation
    $("#button1").fadeIn(); // and fade in the button
};

// On click, pass the length of the message to the function
$(document).click(dialogue.bind(null, message.length));

// Hide the button on page load
$("#button1").hide();
```

```css
#pid { white-space: pre-wrap }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="pid"></p>
<button id="button1">Ooh, here's one! Click to see what it does!</button>
```

Comment: For some reason nothing in the script is affecting the button in my document, so it stays on the page the entire time the text scrolls. The code works perfectly in the snippet, so I want to know what could make it stop functioning. Do I absolutely need the #?

Comment: Make sure the code is included at the end of the body tag or else wrap the code in `$(function() {.......})`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the button when your are done with writing the text, you can add this code to your if statement

```
else{
    document.getElementById("button1").style.display = "block";
}
```

This will show the button when your are done with writing because then this statement is not true: `a <= message.length`

**demo**

```css
#button1{
display:none;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE=HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sandbox</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mainstyle.css">
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>   
    <p id="pid"></p>
    <script>
    
        var a = 1;
        function dialogue(){
            var message = "This message is (hopefully) a successful implementation of JS video game scrolling! <br> <br> Pretty cool, huh? Well, believe it or not, this whole page is a test for a very basic interactive story using HTML/JavaScript! <br> <br> Let's see if we can add some fade-in buttons, shall we? <br> <br> (By the way--you can click anywhere in this window to instantly clear through subsequent text scrolls.)";
            if(a <= message.length) {
                var txt = message.substring(0,a);
                document.getElementById ("pid").innerHTML = txt;
                setTimeout("dialogue()",20);
                a++;
                document.onclick = function(){
                a = message.length;
                };
            }else{
              document.getElementById("button1").style.display = "block";
            }
        };

        dialogue();


    </script>
    <button id="button1">Ooh, here's one! Click to see what it does!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, it's possible. If I get you correctly, you only need to add an else to the function, and make the button visible. Of course if you work with classes, you can easily define a css fade in effect.

```html
<!DOCTYPE=HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sandbox</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mainstyle.css">
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>   
    <p id="pid"></p>
    <script>
    
        var a = 1;
        function dialogue(){
            var message = "This message is (hopefully) a successful implementation of JS video game scrolling! <br> <br> Pretty cool, huh? Well, believe it or not, this whole page is a test for a very basic interactive story using HTML/JavaScript! <br> <br> Let's see if we can add some fade-in buttons, shall we? <br> <br> (By the way--you can click anywhere in this window to instantly clear through subsequent text scrolls.)";
            if(a <= message.length) {
                var txt = message.substring(0,a);
                document.getElementById ("pid").innerHTML = txt;
                setTimeout("dialogue()",20);
                a++;
                document.onclick = function(){
                a = message.length;
                };
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById('button1').style = '';
            }
        };

        dialogue();


    </script>
    <button id="button1" style="display:none;">Ooh, here's one! Click to see what it does!</button>
</body>
</html>
```