# JavaScript - Make function properly run upon clicking a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This a followup to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49687644/javascript-how-to-fade-in-an-invisible-button-element-upon-completion-of-a-fun), sorry for making them so close to each other.

I am trying to have a button disappear upon clicking and then running a subsequent function, but here, clicking on the button makes the first char of message2 appear, then has it fade back in again; continuing to click the button makes each subsequent character appear until none are left, and the second button never appears no matter how many times I click. It should work, so what is the problem here?

EDIT: Somehow slipped my mind to add timer2. Now the effect is closer to what I want, but it doesn't completely match the effect of the original dialogue function (which is what I was going for).

My code:

```js
var message = `This message is (hopefully) a successful implementation of JS video game scrolling!

        Pretty cool, huh? Well, believe it or not, this whole page is a test for a very basic interactive story using HTML/JavaScript!

        Let's see if we can add some fade-in buttons, shall we?

        (By the way--you can click anywhere in this window to instantly clear through subsequent text scrolls.)`;

var timer = setInterval(dialogue, 20);

function dialogue(add = 1) { // By default 1 character is made visible
  var len = $("#pid").text().length + add; // Get desired length
  $("#pid").text(message.substr(0, len)); // Make the change
  if (len < message.length) return; // Nothing more to do
  clearInterval(timer); // All is shown, so stop the animation
  $("#button1").fadeIn(); // and fade in the button
};

// On click, pass the length of the message to the function
$(document).click(dialogue.bind(null, message.length));

var message2 = `Wonderful! Now let's try summoning another button.`

function dialogue2(add2 = 1) {
  $("#button1").hide();
  var timer2 = setInterval(dialogue2,20);
  var len2 = $("#pid2").text().length + add2; // Get desired length
  $("#pid2").text(message2.substr(0, len2)); // Make the change
  if (len2 < message2.length) return; // Nothing more to do
  clearInterval(timer2); // All is shown, so stop the animation
  $("#button2").fadeIn(); // and fade in the button
}

// Hide the button on page load
$("#button1").hide();
$("#button2").hide();
$("#button3").hide();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE=HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Sandbox</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="mainstyle.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <p id="pid"></p>
  <button id="button1" onclick="dialogue2(add2 = 1);">Ooh, here's one! Click to see what it does!</button>
  <p id="pid2"></p>
  <button id="button2">Speak of the devil, and he shall come!</button>
  <p id="pid3"></p>
  <button id="button3">Last time, I promise!</button>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What do you need to do with `button3`? and when it should appear?

Comment: What is `clearInterval(timer2)` supposed to do? There's no `timer2` interval being set.

Comment: That's the problem. You're getting an error on that line, so the next line never executes. Didn't you see the error in the console?

Comment: Also, button3 will not come into play until I know I can successfully duplicate dialogue with similar subsequent functions. It may be that I need to just modify the dialogue function for repetitive use. Should I ask a different question about this?

Comment: Instead of hiding the buttons via javascript. I strongly suggest doing it via css, You could add a class for css selection or just add `#button1, #button2, #button3 {  display: none; }`. In that case it shouldn't "flicker" as it does when running the code snippet. EDIT. it doesn't flicker anymore in my browser without changes of your code. Awkward ;)

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and ask a new, clearer. Mods/admins, feel free to delete this one.