# JavaScript - Modify function to be reusable in later instances?

Tags: javascript, html

This is a followup to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49687644/javascript-how-to-fade-in-an-invisible-button-element-upon-completion-of-a-fun).

I have a function that I would like to make reusable so I don't have to make new, very similar functions over and over to achieve the same effect. Specifically, I would like to know how to change var message *after* the first function instance runs *without* losing the original message.

Here's my code:

```js
        var message = `This message is (hopefully) a successful implementation of JS video game scrolling!

        //Pretty cool, huh? Well, believe it or not, this whole page is a test for a very basic interactive story using HTML/JavaScript!

       // Let's see if we can add some fade-in buttons, shall we?

        //(By the way--you can click anywhere in this window to instantly clear through subsequent text scrolls.)`;

        var timer = setInterval(dialogue, 20);

        function dialogue(add = 1){ // By default 1 character is made visible
            var len = $("#pid").text().length + add; // Get desired length
            $("#pid").text(message.substr(0, len)); // Make the change
            if (len < message.length) return; // Nothing more to do
            clearInterval(timer); // All is shown, so stop the animation
            $("#button1").fadeIn(); // and fade in the button
        };

        // On click, pass the length of the message to the function
        $(document).click(dialogue.bind(null, message.length));
        

        // Hide the button on page load
        $("#button1").hide();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sandbox</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mainstyle.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="pid"></p>
    <button id="button1">Ooh, here's one! Click to see what it does!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit: https://jsfiddle.net/n8Lczdk0/4/

I'm not sure what you mean, but if you wrap everything in a function that takes message as an argument, then it'll be in the dialogue function's closure and you'll be able to update *var message* after you call the wrapper function without dialogue() knowing about it. As they say, *a few lines of code are worth hundreds of prose*:

```
    var message = `This message is (hopefully) a successful implementation of JS video game scrolling!

    Pretty cool, huh? Well, believe it or not, this whole page is a test for a very basic interactive story using HTML/JavaScript!

    Let's see if we can add some fade-in buttons, shall we?

    (By the way--you can click anywhere in this window to instantly clear through subsequent text scrolls.)`;



    const f = message => {
      var timer = setInterval(dialogue, 20);

      function dialogue(add = 1){ // By default 1 character is made visible
        var len = $("#pid").text().length + add; // Get desired length
        $("#pid").text(message.substr(0, len)); // Make the change
        if (len < message.length) return; // Nothing more to do
        clearInterval(timer); // All is shown, so stop the animation
        $("#button1").fadeIn(); // and fade in the button
      };

      // On click, pass the length of the message to the function
      $(document).click(dialogue.bind(null, message.length));

      // Hide the button on function call
      $("#button1").hide();
    }


    f(message)



    message = "some new value"
```

So above, I'm essentially wrapping your whole js code in a function that takes message as an argument. Kinda like currying your dialogue function.

You could also pass your ids as arguments and make it fully reusable. Just pass a message and DOM ids to the function and the magic unrolls with associated buttons fading in as various texts show up.

Hope this helped, cheers,

thomas

Comment: Works great, but now I have another question: if I wanted to call the new function instance with a button click, how would I go about doing that, exactly? Because <button onclick = "f(var, var, var)"></button> won't work.

Comment: UPDATE: I found a way through onclick, but when the button is pressed, the scrolling effect no longer occurs. (Note that I haven't changed any of your code when copying it over.) What could be causing this?

Comment: NVM, fixed it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You can try with below one way

You can pass one optional argument(message) to the function and check if it is passed then use that message otherwise use default original message.

```js
var message = `This message is (hopefully) a successful implementation of JS video game scrolling!

        Pretty cool, huh? Well, believe it or not, this whole page is a test for a very basic interactive story using HTML/JavaScript!

        Let's see if we can add some fade-in buttons, shall we?

        (By the way--you can click anywhere in this window to instantly clear through subsequent text scrolls.)`;

        var timer = setInterval(dialogue, 20);

        function dialogue(add = 1, custom_message){ // By default 1 character is made visible
            var temp_message;
            
            if(typeof custom_message === "undefined") {
              temp_message = message;
            }
            else {
              temp_message = custom_message;
            }
            
            var len = $("#pid").text().length + add; // Get desired length
            $("#pid").text(temp_message.substr(0, len)); // Make the change
            if (len < temp_message.length) return; // Nothing more to do
            clearInterval(timer); // All is shown, so stop the animation
            $("#button1").fadeIn(); // and fade in the button
        };

        // On click, pass the length of the message to the function
        $(document).click(dialogue.bind(null, message.length));
        
        

        // Hide the button on page load
        $("#button1").hide();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE=HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sandbox</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mainstyle.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="pid"></p>
    <button id="button1">Ooh, here's one! Click to see what it does!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply ask for another parameter in dialogue() for the new message. You can then create an array of messages, from which you can choose whatever message you'd like to pass. This will ensure that all your messages are saved.

```
var messages = ["Message one", "Message two", "Message three"];
```